# Is it possible to delegate a root domain (example.com) to other nameserver?

Tags: dns

I am in a situation whereby some of my clients either register their own domain name or they have another company manage it.

Is there anyway to get them to set their registrar's nameserver settings to a intermediary nameserver which I can then map to another one?

As I understand I can do this with subdomains using a NS records, but can't find a way to do this with a root domain e.g example.com.

Comment: I'm afraid I believe this is not possible. If a zone has been delegated to a particular nameserver, clients will expect that nameserver to have the appropriate records, and probably won't even re query it for NS records, let alone respect these.

Comment: Hi Emily, thanks for confirming this. This isn't possible, but for my particular use case I found it might make sense to use a seperate forwarding DNS server under our control to redirect particular zones. http://www.zytrax.com/books/dns/ch4/#forwarding .

Comment: Emily would you like to put that comment as an answer and I can accept it?